# Butterknife gradle error on Android Studio 3.0 due to android-apt plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, butterknife, android-studio-3.0

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.0 I had some issues with gradle that I was able to fix checking on the developers [website](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

However, I was not able to find how to fix the issue with the `apply plugin: 'android-apt'` I have tried several things such as removing it from the project gradle and add it to the app gradle as `annotationProcessor 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'` . also removed the apt, etc, etc.

Anyway, Studio is complaining about it.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    ext {
        supportLibVersion = '27.0.0'
        firebaseLibVersion = '11.4.2'
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

APP GRADLE

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'android-apt'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
.....

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: instead of apt use `annotationProcessor` and remove    `classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'`

Comment: For more context on why it wasn't working. `apt` isn't supported anymore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use apt plugin, add the dependency like this:

```
compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1"
annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1"
```

[Reference](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

Comment: [original issue thread](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/963#issuecomment-342400475)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in hurry you can disable that thing.

As per Document

> If you are experiencing issues migrating to the new dependency
>   resolution strategy, you can restore behavior to that of Android
>   plugin 2.3.0 by setting includeCompileClasspath true. However,
>   restoring behavior to version 2.3.0 is not recommended.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And one more thing you have to define `flavorDimensions "default"` property in buildTypes tag in gradle file.

You can check more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#flavor-dimensions).