# I have updated android studio version to 3.1 - leads to error while running app

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Recently I updated my Android Studio version to 3.1. After updating my project is not building and instead is giving me the following error:

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForStageDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:253)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
```

I don't know what the error is in my code because the log isn't pointing to any of my class files. Can any one help me to solve this issue?

after updating project level build.gradle file I got different error [image]

This is my gradle file

```
        // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.31'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
            //classpath 'com.splunk:mint-gradle-android-plugin:5.2.2'
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
            flatDir {
                dirs 'aars'
            }
        }

    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

    ext {

        minSdkVersion = 16
        targetSdkVersion = 26

        compileSdkVersion = 27
        buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"

        supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.0'
        playServicesVersion = '12.0.1'
        awsVersion = '2.3.4'
        OKHTTP_VERSION = '3.4.1'
        archRoomVersion = "1.0.0"
    }
```

Here is my app level build.gradle file

```
        buildscript {
        dependencies {
            // classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
            //classpath 'com.splunk:mint-gradle-android-plugin:5.2.2'
        }

        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
            //maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
            //maven { url uri('mint-plugin-repo-5.2.2') }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/repo' }
        //maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url uri('mint-plugin-repo-5.2.2') }
    }


    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    //apply plugin: 'com.splunk.mint.gradle.android.plugin'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'


    androidExtensions {
        experimental = true
    }

    android {
        compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
            targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion
            multiDexEnabled true
            versionCode 41//3 //
            versionName "0.4.1"  //"1.0.2" //
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }


        productFlavors {

        }



        signingConfigs {
            release {

            }
        }



        buildTypes {

            debug {
                debuggable true
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            }

            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
                debuggable false
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
        buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation(name: 'nccsdk-0.0.9-stage', ext: 'aar')
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibraryVersion"
        implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
        implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$playServicesVersion"
        implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.github.frangsierra:rx2firebase:1.1.3'
        implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
        implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
        implementation "com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:$supportLibraryVersion"
        implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'
        implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
        kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
        implementation 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
        kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
        implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
        //annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
        implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:2.3.1'
        implementation 'com.auth0.android:lock:1.14.1'
        implementation 'com.auth0.android:identity-core:1.14.1'
        implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.4'
        //3rd Party Libraries
        implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.9.1'
        implementation group: 'com.zendesk', name: 'sdk', version: '1.11.0.1'
        implementation 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.3.4.1'
        implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
        implementation 'com.nikhilpanju.recyclerviewenhanced:recyclerviewenhanced:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
        implementation 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.4.0'
        implementation 'com.apptentive:apptentive-android:5.0.2'
        implementation 'com.vicmikhailau:MaskedEditText:2.0.3'
        implementation 'me.srodrigo:androidhintspinner:1.0.0'
        implementation 'ca.barrenechea.header-decor:header-decor:0.2.8'
        implementation 'com.github.HotBitmapGG:RingProgressBar:V1.2.2'
        implementation 'com.patloew.rxlocation:rxlocation:1.0.3'
        implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12'

        implementation 'q.rorbin:badgeview:1.1.2'
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.1@aar') {
            transitive = true
        }
        implementation('com.stripe:stripe-android:1.0.4@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        implementation('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.13.0@aar') {
            transitive = true;
        }
        androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
        //implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib-jre8', version: '1.2.10'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion;
        kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:" + rootProject.archRoomVersion;
        implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:' + rootProject.archRoomVersion;
        implementation project(path: ':zxing')

        implementation 'com.splunk:mint-android-sdk:5.2.2'

        //SDK related libs
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kinesis:2.4.4'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-iot:2.4.4'
        implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.4.4'


    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"`

Comment: Update your question with build.gradle of your app module.

Comment: I have updated my project level build.gradle file compileSdkVersion = 27
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"

Comment: Still, it might be useful to have a look at gradle file.

Comment: I have updated with gradle file

Comment: I believe you need to update your library versions. For example, update ` com.google.gms.google-services ` to 3.2.1. Also you shouldn't put using your project's build.gradle too much. Prefer `app/build.gradle` (i.e. app module's gradle file).

Comment: It could be that your problem is similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955653/butterknife-gradle-error-on-android-studio-3-0-due-to-android-apt-plugin

Comment: I have added my app level build.gradle file.

Comment: How can I update com.google.gms.google-services version because I added it as a plugin. Check my gradle file.

Comment: In that link they asked to replace "apt" with "annotationProcessor". But in my project I have mentioned it as a "kapt" not "apt"...Anyway I tried replacing "kapt" with "annotationProcessor" still problem is there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167817/discussion-between-sufian-and-anbarasu-chinna).

Comment: Can you set your minifyEnabled false, and check if it's giving you issues properly?

Comment: I changed minifyEnabled value to false. Still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When upgrading to 3.1, I updated all the libraries to the latest version and got the same problem as you.

I rolled back the build.gradle file and it compiles without issue.
I then updated one library at a time and found that the retrofit was the one causing the problem (2.4.0 didn't work for me, but 2.3.0 works).

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
```

you can try the rollback method too.

[image]

**edit**

you can try adding this into your proguard file. (it fixed my error and I can update to 2.4.0 without issue)

```
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
```

I notice that I have some warnings in my build (see image)
[image]

I went to google "okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform: can't find referenced class org.conscrypt.OpenSSLProvider"

and it led me to the following:  https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/3922

which leads me to this link: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/5fe3cc2d089810032671d6135ad137af6f491d28/README.md#proguard (which told me to add the above to the proguard file).

Comment: Am already using this retrofit version 2.3.0. No idea what to do further. Any idea?

Comment: did you update any libraries after changing to AS 3.1? if so, you can try to revert back to the old library version.

Comment: I reverted all of my dependency.

Comment: This is the same error am getting. You Know how to solve my issue.

Comment: You are awesome man... reverted kotlin to previous version solved this issue...you saves my another 2 day...

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna Do see my edit, I manage to update to use the latest versions.

Comment: I will try later and let you know @Angel Koh...Hope this also very useful

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @AnbarasuChinna kotlin version?

Answer (score 0):

**Use below**

-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**

## Add below if using Java 8

-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8